# Trying to replace a loop with purrr::map_dbl and using corrr::correlate

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to find a correlation of all variables within a grouping variable. Specifically I am trying to use purrr to do this to replace a loop that I've been using. But I've gotten a bit stuck, partially because I want to use two functions when applying over the vector of interest. For example:

```
## load packages
library(corrr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
```

Without any groups this works fine (and this is the base of what I'd like to do):

```
iris %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  correlate() %>%
  stretch()
```

But I get stymied when I try to group this:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  correlate() %>%
  stretch()
```

> Error in stats::cor(x = x, y = y, use = use, method = method) :    'x'
>   must be numeric

So my thought is to use `purrr`... seems like the exact place where I use it right?

```
iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  map_dbl(~correlate) ## then how do i incorporate `stretch()`
```

> Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a closure to a double

Obviously this is wrong but I am not sure exactly how I should apply `map_*` here...

This is the loop what I am trying to replace which does give the correct output but I'd prefer to not use it - it is less flexible than the `purrr` approach:

```
Species <- unique(iris$Species)
df <- c()
for(i in seq_along(Species)){
  u <- iris %>%
    filter(Species == Species[i]) %>%
    select(-Species) %>%
    correlate() %>%
    stretch() %>%
    mutate(Species = Species[i])

  df <- rbind(df, u)
}

df

# A tibble: 48 x 4
              x            y         r Species
          <chr>        <chr>     <dbl>  <fctr>
 1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Length        NA  setosa
 2 Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.7425467  setosa
 3 Sepal.Length Petal.Length 0.2671758  setosa
 4 Sepal.Length  Petal.Width 0.2780984  setosa
 5  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 0.7425467  setosa
 6  Sepal.Width  Sepal.Width        NA  setosa
 7  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 0.1777000  setosa
 8  Sepal.Width  Petal.Width 0.2327520  setosa
 9 Petal.Length Sepal.Length 0.2671758  setosa
10 Petal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.1777000  setosa
```

So in sum, can someone outline how to use `purrr` when I need to use two functions. In other words, how do I replace the loop above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more flexible summary syntax with `group_by %>% do`, where in `do`, you can access each subgroup with `.` and apply `correlate` and `stretch` just like a normal data frame:

```
library(corrr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(
    select(., -Species) %>% correlate() %>% stretch()
)

# A tibble: 48 x 4
# Groups:   Species [3]
#   Species            x            y         r
#    <fctr>        <chr>        <chr>     <dbl>
# 1  setosa Sepal.Length Sepal.Length        NA
# 2  setosa Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.7425467
# 3  setosa Sepal.Length Petal.Length 0.2671758
# 4  setosa Sepal.Length  Petal.Width 0.2780984
# 5  setosa  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 0.7425467
# 6  setosa  Sepal.Width  Sepal.Width        NA
# 7  setosa  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 0.1777000
# 8  setosa  Sepal.Width  Petal.Width 0.2327520
# 9  setosa Petal.Length Sepal.Length 0.2671758
#10  setosa Petal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.1777000
# ... with 38 more rows
```

---

With `purrr`, you can nest data under each group first and then `map` over it:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% nest() %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, compose(stretch, correlate))) %>% 
    unnest()

# A tibble: 48 x 4
#   Species            x            y         r
#    <fctr>        <chr>        <chr>     <dbl>
# 1  setosa Sepal.Length Sepal.Length        NA
# 2  setosa Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.7425467
# 3  setosa Sepal.Length Petal.Length 0.2671758
# 4  setosa Sepal.Length  Petal.Width 0.2780984
# 5  setosa  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 0.7425467
# 6  setosa  Sepal.Width  Sepal.Width        NA
# 7  setosa  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 0.1777000
# 8  setosa  Sepal.Width  Petal.Width 0.2327520
# 9  setosa Petal.Length Sepal.Length 0.2671758
#10  setosa Petal.Length  Sepal.Width 0.1777000
# ... with 38 more rows
```

Comment: Ok! I am going to wait for a little though to accept this as I am wondering if there is a purrr-based answer. Or are you saying that it isn't possible to do this in purrr?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it in `purrr`; I thought `group_by %>% do` is pretty simple already. Provided an alternative with `purrr`, see the update.

Comment: Doubly helpful! My understanding was that the preferred way of doing things was via `map_*` rather than `do` which is why I asked for that approach.

Comment: I think you are correct performance wise. `map` is most likely faster when there are a lot of groups. Haven't paid too much attention to the timing though.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Any chance to help me to change corer function to hmisc? I would like to integrate the correlation coefficient and its p-values. @Psidom